# error while installing the yohkenn/symfony-jasper-report-bundle via composer

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

I tried to install the yohkenn/symfony-jasper-report-bundle with composer using this command

```
composer require yohkenn/jasper-report-bundle
```

but i get this error

```
    C:\wamp\www\
C:\wamp\www\Syslife_new>composer require yohkenn/jasper-report-bundle 1.1
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package yohkenn/jasper-report-bundle could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package
 name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
>composer require yohkenn/jasper-report-bundle 1.1
    ./composer.json has been updated
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

      Problem 1
        - The requested package yohkenn/jasper-report-bundle could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package
     name.

    Potential causes:
     - A typo in the package name
     - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
       see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

    Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

    Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Here is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "um/frontal",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "type": "project",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "app/AppKernel.php",
            "app/AppCache.php"
        ]
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.12",
        "symfony/symfony": "~3.0",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.8",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "^1.6",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.0",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "^1.1",
        "vich/uploader-bundle": "^1.3",
        "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "^1.4",
        "tetranz/select2entity-bundle": "2.*",
        "geekcom/phpjasper": "1.*",
        "umpirsky/symfony-upgrade-fixer": "^0.1.6"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.2"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin",
        "platform": {
            "php": "5.5.12"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know what they mean by "minimum-stability" Can someone help me ?

Comment: can you post your composer.json files?

Comment: Sure i've updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm...

I think you have some typo in your command.

When I run a command from your question I get a similar error.

But, when I use command from https://packagist.org/packages/yohkenn/symfony-jasper-report-bundle

`composer require yohkenn/symfony-jasper-report-bundle`

everything goes well.

I think you are missing a `symfony` part in your command.